# Amazon Product API - How to get items for sale by price?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, amazon-web-services

I have a strage requirement from a client, he needs to display a ramdom selection (100 - 200 items from mixed categories) of products for sale on & shipped by Amazon but ordered by price. The idea is to allow people find gift ideas based a user input price point.

I have been looking through the API docs but cannot see an obvious way to find search by price, I am thinking of writing a script to "copy" large parts of the amazon product catalogue into a local database & have it update every few weeks, then use this for user searches, but this does not feel right / their must be a better way.

Has anyone any experience with this type of problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/Welcome.html). Using this API you would want to perform a SearchIndex-ItemSearch query. Possible parameters to ItemSearch are available on the API Docs [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/USSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html)

You can see in the docs that you cannot query by `MinimumPrice` and `MaximumPrice` on `SearchIndex: All`. However, if you search specific indexes, it allows you to do a price related search.

I would guess that you can agree with your client which categories should the items be from. Then you can just query them one by one.

Amazon's database changes very often. Hence, caching data for a week without updating may not be desirable.